# Access Denied when trying to get an image through AWS s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

The way I'm uploading the image is the following:

```
        $file = $request->featured_image;
        $filename = time().'.'.$request->featured_image->extension();
        $file->storeAs('images/', $filename, 's3');

        $course = Course::create([
            'featured_image' => $filename,
        ]);
```

The problem is when I tried to get it with blade:

```
<img src="{{Storage::disk('s3')->url($course->featured_image)}}" alt="course">
```

When I try to access the URL, I get something like

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0W0NVXNHFRJY7MYP</RequestId>
<HostId>Xex73PhCOr1fm6cnhkDTOeqppblAYIrUtZ1jO81Jh3yjEhIHzvRcWsAg22VL5QrIoXcgefX6GTc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

For the permissions of AWS, I gave full access to S3. So I'm not sure why is this happening. The file DOES get saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you have a private bucket, you can issue temporary URLs really easily though to get around this. (or open up the permissions on your bucket)

example:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($image, now()->addMinutes(30))
```

Edit:
Bucket privacy selection ->
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The issue is that in the permissions, I created a user with full access to it, so that's why I'm not so sure about what's happening. (tried and still got access denied)

Comment: I've left in an edit the image for the bucket's default access - which is separate to the user access which you could try setting to block nothing

Comment: Also make sure you've run `php artisan config:clear` with all of these values set in your `.env`: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_BUCKET

Comment: weird, I got the same settings as you do.

Comment: Even if you create a user with full permissions the URL you generate does not transfer the permissions to the public (since `url()` creates a public URL). Did `temporaryUrl()` also not work?

Comment: Hey, @BenGooding Your answer was correct, it was just missing the directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When saving the image to S3 replace the following line

`$file->storeAs('images/', $filename, 's3');`

with

`$file->storePublicly('images/', $filename, 's3');`

also it looks like you are saving the image to `images/filename.jpg` however when attempting to retrieve, you're only passing the filename, try the below line and let me know how you go

`{{Storage::disk('s3')->url('images/'.$course->featured_image)}}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all possible solutions, but they didn't work. To overcome this problem, ensure you

1. Set the visibility of your file to public

   ```php
   $pathfile = $imageFile->store($path. '/'. $imageName, 's3');
   Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($pathfile, 'public');
   $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($pathfile);
   ```
2. Set up your bucket policy

   You can use the free [Amazon policy generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to do that. Ensure you select **S3 Bucket Policy** Type and paste your **Bucket ARN** into the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) field.

   ```json
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Id": "Policy1706967276326",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt1706967269162",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*",
               "Action": "s3:*",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::market-access-s3"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   [image: Amazon Policy Generator Screenshot]
3. Edit your **Object Ownership**
   By default Object ownership will be set to **ACLs disabled(recommended)**. Change it **ACLs enabled** and save your changes.
   [image: Object Ownership page screenshot]
4. Save a new file to s3 and access the link on a browser