# why is my S3 TemporaryURL no longer working

Tags: temporary

My laravel controller has this code that would generate a temporary URL for my files on S3 and send it to the users for temporary access.

here is the code:

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl('Reports/report_signed2.pdf', now()->addMinutes(1));
```

I have configured my s3 storage properly and this is used to be working until recently, the url returns Denied Access.

Did some changes implemented in AWS s3 security and need some updating to my bucket or iam?
I did not change anything to policies to my IAM.

My IAM has three Policies:

1. AmazonS3FullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. iaminlinepolicy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetAccessGrants"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::hris-pangasinan",
                "arn:aws:s3:::hris-pangasinan/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

3. laravel-policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetAccessGrants"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::hris-pangasinan",
                "arn:aws:s3:::hris-pangasinan/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you very much

I have been experimenting but to no avail.

Comment: How are you authenticating with the bucket?  Could your API Key have expired?

Comment: I configured my laravel project with IAM access key and as of today this access key is still valid

Comment: the generated temporary url is this: 

http://hris-pangasinan.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Reports/report_signed2.pdf?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&amp;X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIARYDQ4T4GREIW4E46%2F20231207%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20231207T061518Z&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Expires=60&amp;X-Amz-Signature=baea03f3e71427f98baa294ec56ab052a63c58ec554d4fb25fb694a3cfe3bdf9

I dont know if the keyword 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD' in the generated temporary URL has bearing why I get Access Denied.

Comment: That's the extent of my understanding.  Perhaps this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509699/access-denied-when-trying-to-get-an-image-through-aws-s3